# Gatling get variable out of feeder

Tags: gatling

My Gatling version is 2.2.0, for example:

```
# resource.csv file
===============
user
user1
user2

# object file
===============
object REntity {
  val feeder = csv("resources.csv").circular

  val entity =
  // ==================
  // log in
  // ==================
    feed(feeder)
      .exec(
        http("example")
          .post("/authentication?name=${user}")
          .body(session => s"${Utils.getCredential(user)}")
      ).exitHereIfFailed.pause(Config.ThinkTime)
}
```

`Utils.getCredential(user: String): String`is simply a function which accept a user name, and return a credential string.

As you see, the user name are stored in `resources.csv` file. I could simply refer to it by `.post("/authentication?name=${user}")`. But how could I refer to it as a variable like `${Utils.getCredential(user))}`, this will raise error.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I searched Gatling's docs, found out the answer [here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/session/session_api.html#getting-attributes).

It has two sections introducing 1). setting attributes and 2) getting attributes.

Basically speaking, the way to get attributes should be:

```
// say resources.csv looks like this:
// =====================
// user,entityID
// Jim,1001
// Mike,1002

val feeder = csv("resources.csv").circular
val name = session("user").as[String] // => "Jim"
```

The answer should be:

```
object REntity {
  val feeder = csv("resources.csv").circular

  val entity =
  // ==================
  // log in
  // ==================
    feed(feeder)
      .exec(
        http("example")
          .post("/authentication?name=${user}")
          .body(session => Utils.getCredential(session("user").as[String]))
      ).exitHereIfFailed.pause(Config.ThinkTime)
}
```